# How long is it safe to store an unopened iPod Classic?

Tags: ipod

I just bought an iPod classic after the discontinuation, and I already have a working one, so I just want to store this one until its needed.

How long is it ok to just leave it in the box? I read once that you're not supposed to let a battery sit with no charge in it, and the date on the iPod box says 2009, meaning this thing almost definitely has no charge right? Should I start it on charge cycles or just leave it in the box?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to:

Charge the battery to about 30%

Read more here:

[Store it in dry and cool place.](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_store_batteries)

Comment: Why? What's special about charging to 20%?

Comment: It is the recommended charge to store batteries. When you buy a new device there is always some charge in it, that is the same reason.

Comment: But why that number? That's a very specific number to put out there without much of an explanation.

Comment: @IanC. see this for more details http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_store_batterie